# В Laravel требуется доработка скрипта на JS ES6

Tags: javascript, laravel, ecmascript-6

в проекте на Laravel необходима доработка скрипта на JS ES6 может кто помочь? отправим небольшое вознаграждение в виде 500 рублей

подробнее в видеотз
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/KLh4%2FMHYNND9tv

Проект
https://github.com/lagavu/freelara.git

CategoryManager
https://github.com/lagavu/freelara/blob/master/resources/js/CategoryManager.js

AttributeManager
https://github.com/lagavu/freelara/blob/master/resources/js/AttributeManager.js

Comment: Дык) не то место для таких вопросов))

Comment: понимаю но мало ли решил попробовать) можете посоветовать где много JS-ников? попробовал на хабре и фриланс.ру биржах фриланса.. тишина...